# Thoughts on using screen width and height for mobile detection

Tags: javascript, mobile

I think screen.Width and screen.Height are good enough to detect mobile device. Roughly If they are lesser than certain value like 800, then it's a mobile device.
But when I searched around for a solution for mobile detection, they are never mentioned. Is there any downside to use these two value for mobile detection?

Comment: It depends _why_ you need to know if they have a mobile device or not. If you're just trying to make sure the page looks good at their screen size, then screen width is all you really need to care about. But if you needed to know if they have a mobile device because, say, you need to know if they have a touchscreen or something like that, then you should use other methods to determine their device type.

Comment: "Mobile" is a pretty awful metric for anything. Does the screen size matter? Worry about the screen size. Does the connection speed matter? Worry about the connection speed. Does having a touch screen matter? Worry about having a touch screen. Don't use logic chains like "I have to do something special on touch screens, therefore I will do something special on mobile, therefore I will do something special on small screens".